# What is "Jargon" on Port 148?

Tags: networking, firewall

Anyone know about the "Jargon" protocol/service/whatever-it-is?
Have Googled looking at dozens of websites, emailed the IANA contact (no response), etc.
Jargon is listed as Port 148 ... as is CRONUS-SUPPORT sometimes.

Comment: The email address is correct and it works and it's me.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, Jargon is example internet protocol for unfinished Bill Weinman's book ["Writing Internet Services in Perl"](http://perlbook.com/)

Comment: This is correct. I registered this port years ago along with a book I was writing. The book was completed but never published. I may revisit it some day.